# C++ not reading in my % Operator (error: no match for 'operator%')

Tags: c++

Comp Sci 201 Student, having a lot of trouble on this lab. I'm sure I should be correct at this point, but it keeps throwing out my code, citing the %, but I don't undestand why it wouldn't work.

```css
//Do all your includes. Don't forget we're using vectors and strings
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

unsigned userNum = 0;

int main(){
   
//Step 1: Create a Vector

vector<string>cellNum;
   for(int i= 0; i < 20;++i) {
   cellNum.push_back("x");
}

{

 cin >> userNum;
   srand(userNum);

   
for(int d = 0; d < 10; ++d) {

   for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
      
      if (rand() % 2 == 0) {
         cellNum.at(i) = " ";
      }
      else {
         cellNum.at(i) = "*";
         
      }
   }
   vector<string>cellStor;
   for(int i= 0; i < 20;++i) {
   cellStor.push_back("x");
   }
   
   for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
      int cellStatus = 0;
      int vecSize;
      
      if (cellNum.at(i) == "*") {
         cellStatus = cellStatus+1;
      }
      if ((cellNum.at((i - 1) + vecSize) % vecSize) == "*") {
         cellStatus = cellStatus+1;
      }
      if ((cellNum.at( (i + 1) % vecSize) == "*")) {
         cellStatus = cellStatus+1;
       }
       cout << cellStatus;
   }
   }
}


//Step 5: Make a new vector

//Step 6: Walk through the old vector - at each point count the number of cells alive

//Step 7: Based on the number of cells alive, set the new vector to be alive or dead

//Step 8: Once cells are accounted for, set the old vector equal to the new one to do a full copy

for(int j = 0; j<20; ++j) {
      cout << cellNum.at(j);
   }
   
   cout << endl;


}
```

And here are the error messsages

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:49:42: error: no match for 'operator%' (operand types are '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}' and 'int')
       if ((cellNum.at((i - 1) + vecSize) % vecSize) == "*") {
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~

Comment: `cellNum` is a `std::vector<std::string>` so `cellNum.at((i - 1) + vecSize)` yields a `std::string&`. There is no `%` operator defined for this type. BTW, next time post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) rather than all the code you could find.

Comment: I think I've guessed the right answer :) Based on experience with similar questions, I'd like to preemptively ask you not to delete this. Others will find it helpful, believe it or not.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Sure thing, glad my stupidity can help others in the future =)

Answer (score 0):

Mind the parens. `cellNum.at((i - 1) + vecSize) % vecSize` goes out of array bounds and then the `%` operation is nonsense, hence the error message.

It looks like you want `cellNum.at((i - 1 + vecSize) % vecSize)` which does modulo indexing into the array.